# CFG Equivalent of regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, computation-models

So I was wondering something about the Chomsky hierarchy.

DFAs (and NFAs) accept regular languages, while NPDAs accept context-free languages.

Right-regular or left-regular grammars produce regular languages, while context-free grammars produce context-free languages.

Regular expressions represent regular languages - but is there a context-free equivalent?  i.e. is there some additional term we could allow to appear in a regular expression such that regular expressions with that functionality now represent context-free languages?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Chomsky-Schützenberger theorem](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free/19799#19799)?

Comment: A (rather technical) answer, where star-operator is replaced by least fixed point (equivalent to recursive formulation as in CFG) is given by our cstheory cousins: [Does there exist an extension of regular expressions that captures the context free languages?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16904/does-there-exist-an-extension-of-regular-expressions-that-captures-the-context-f)

Comment: [Perl's regular expressions support recursion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?_PARNO_)-(?-_PARNO_)-(?+_PARNO_)-(?R)-(?0)), so a subset expresses the CFLs.

Comment: Hendrik - I think that answers it pretty clearly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A (rather technical) answer, where star-operator is replaced by least fixed point (equivalent to recursive formulation as in CFG) is given by our cstheory cousins: [Does there exist an extension of regular expressions that captures the context free languages?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16907/12122)

The author (Neel Krishnaswami) of that answer does not know an original source of his construction, but a later comment by Tim Schaeffer refers to the 1973 book *Formal Languages* by Arto Salomaa. In chapter VI.11 Salomaa introduces *regular-like expressions*. That book might not be in your possession, but in turn refers to *A characterization of context-free languages*, Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 1973, by Jozef Gruska, which is [open access](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(71)80023-5).

The operator Gruska considers is the following, I loosely quote from his paper. Let $\sigma$ be a symbol and $L,L_1$ be languages. 
The $\sigma$-substitution of $L_1$ into $L$, denoted by $L \overset{\sigma}{\uparrow}L_1$ is defined by

$$ L \overset{\sigma}{\uparrow}L_1 = \{ x_0 y_1x_1 \dots x_{k-1} y_k x_k \mid x_0 \sigma x_1 \dots x_{k-1} \sigma x_k\in L, \text{no $\sigma$ in }x_i, y_i\in L_1 \}.$$

After noting that he operation $\overset{\sigma}{\uparrow}$ is associative one defines the $\sigma$-iteration as

$$ L^\sigma = \{z \mid z\in L \cup L\overset{\sigma}{\uparrow}L \cup L\overset{\sigma}{\uparrow}L\overset{\sigma}{\uparrow}L \cup \dots \text{ does not contain an occurrence of } \sigma \}.$$

Note that if we have only a single variable, like $S\to aSbS \mid \lambda$ then this substitution closure $\{aSbS, \lambda\}^S$  is indeed the language generated by the grammar.