# Can we define CFL without grammars or automata?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, computation-models

The set of [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) $R$ over an [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_(formal_languages)) $\Sigma$ can be defined as the smallest set satisfying [these 5 axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Formal_definition):

- Empty language: $\{\} \in R$
- Singleton languages: $\forall a \in \Sigma : \{a\} \in R$
- Closure under union: $\forall A, B \in R : A \cup B \in R$
- Closure under concatenation: $\forall A, B \in R : A B \in R$
- Closure under [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star): $\forall A \in R: A^* = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A^i = \{\varepsilon\} \cup A \cup A^2 \cup \ldots \in R $

Is there a similar way to define the set of context-free languages in terms of set operations, without invoking [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) or [pushdown automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)?

Comment: Does this old question on expressions for cf-languages answer your own question, or are you interested in another generalization of regularity? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59923/cfg-equivalent-of-regular-expressions/

Comment: [Chomsky-Schützenberger](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free/) comes to mind as well.

Comment: See also [this very closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/813/98).

Comment: Would it be OK to narrow this question down as *Can CFLs be characterized in terms of their closure properties?*?